# Mysql Last Insert ID Graphql

Tags: mysql, node.js, graphql

I am using GraphQL and node to manipulate a MySQL database. 
I am however confused at how I go about inserting a record into a table after successfully inserting into the previous table using the Last Insert ID of the former.

```
const Mutation = new GraphQLObjectType({
        AddAuthor: {
            type: AuthorType,
            args: {
                name: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
                age: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt) },
            },
            async resolve(parent, args){
                let data = {
                    name: args.name,
                    age: args.age
                };

                const saveAuthor = await knex.insert(data).returning('id').into('authors');

                if(saveAuthor){
                    const insert_id = saveAuthor[0]; //from previous insertion
                    **//Perform a mutation to add the ID into another table which already has a mutation field.**
                }
            }
        },
});
```

how possible is this? Thanks in advance